# End a .each and a setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to figure out stop/start buttons using javascript and jQuery. I have a jsfiddle set up to try to understand it but I can't get it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/kkx7m88c/

The start button should turn each box red one at a time. The stop button should revert all boxes back to blue and stop any more from turning red until the start button is pressed again. Currently, the stop button will turn all boxes blue but doesn't stop the play function, meaning that boxes that hadn't been turned red yet don't stop. They turn red.

Here is my js:

```
// new class turns the boxes red with css

function goClasses(item, container) {
    $(container).removeClass('stopped');
    $(item).addClass('new');
}

function stopClasses(item, container) {
    $(item).removeClass('new');
    $(container).addClass('stopped');
}


$('#go').mousedown(function () {
    $('.box').each(function(i){
        var item = $(this);
        var container = $('.selection');
        setTimeout(function () {
            goClasses(item, container);
        }, 500 * i);
        if ($(container).hasClass('stopped')) {
            //clearTimeout(); /* this doesn't appear to do anything */
            //return false; /* this stops the 'go' button from working properly when clicked again after the 'stop' button has clicked */
        }
    });
});

$('#stop').mousedown(function () {
    $('.box').each(function (i) {
        var item = $(this);
        var container = $('.selection');
        stopClasses(item, container);
    });
});
```

It's my understanding that if I could just end the setTimeout and the .each in the mousedown section that it would work... but maybe I have it totally off. Maybe I should be using setInterval() instead? I'm new to jQuery so I'm still figuring it all out!

Comment: I don't think your problem is with timer, it is because of the loop that goes on. Try setting a flag from stop button and check it in start function to break the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store a reference to the timer and cancel it

```
$('#go').mousedown(function () {
    $('.box').each(function(i){
        var item = $(this);
        var container = $('.selection');
        var timer = setTimeout(function () {  //store the id that the setTimeout returns
            goClasses(item, container);
        }, 500 * i);
        item.data("timer", timer);  //store it as a data attribute
    });
});

$('#stop').mousedown(function () {
    $('.box').each(function (i) {
        var item = $(this);
        window.clearTimeout(item.data("timer"));  //check the data attribute for the timer and cancel it
        var container = $('.selection');
        stopClasses(item, container);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid `setTimeout()` completely by exploiting jQuery's `.delay()` and `.promise()`.

This has the advantage that you can use jQuery's `.stop()` to kill the delays and halt the entire process.

```
function goClasses($item, $container) {
    $container.removeClass('stopped');
    $item.addClass('new');
}

function stopClasses($item, $container) {
    $item.removeClass('new');
    $container.addClass('stopped');
}

$('#go').on('click', function () {
    var $selection = $(".selection");
    if(!$selection.data('running')) {
        $('.box').get().reduce(function(p, box) {
            return p.then(function() {
                var $box = $(box);
                goClasses($box, $selection);
                return $box.delay(500).promise();
            });
        }, $.when());
        $selection.data('running', true);
    }
});

$('#stop').on('click', function () {
    stopClasses($('.box').stop(), $('.selection').data('running', false));
});
```

Also included is a mechanism to make the "go" button better behaved in case the user clicks it again while an animation sequence is underway.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kkx7m88c/1/)**

**Explanation**

The approach taken on this answer is reasonably advanced, so please don't worry if you cannot grasp it immediately.

If you are not famliar with jQuery's Deferreds/Promises, then you will need to do some background reading on the [Deferred Object](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) and be aware that the [.promise()](https://api.jquery.com/promise/) method makes a promise available associated with completion of an animation (including a delay).

You also need to understand javascript's [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method.

The heart of this anwer is `$('.box').get().reduce(...)`, which creates an array of `.box` elements, then processes that array to build a promise chain seeded with a resolved jQuery promise returned by `$.when()`.

As each of the promises in the chain becomes fulfilled (indicating an animation step's completion), so the next step is executed, the visible aspect of which is `goClasses($box, $selection)`. The statement `return $box.delay(500).promise()` imposes the required delay of 500ms between steps.

The "stop" process simply calls `.stop()` on all `.box` elements, nullifying any pending `.delay(500)` and ensuring that the associated promise will never become fulfilled. The animation sequence ceases.

The `$('.selection').data('running')` boolean is managed such that it indicates whether or not an animation is running (and reset). When `true`, this boolean is used to disallow another animation sequence from starting.

*I've just realised that `$('.selection').data('running')` is not necessary. I could test `$('.selection').hasClass('stopped')` instead*

Comment: this is a little above my head... Could you explain what's going on here a bit? I seems more concise than using the setTimeout() but I'm not able to follow.

Comment: @Alana, I've added an explanation but, as I say, please don't worry if you don't get it. Come back here when you've got some more javascript under your belt.